# Does rich:messages tag need to be in an a4j:region?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, ajax4jsf

The web app I'm working on sometimes has a <rich:messages> tag inside of an <a4j:region> tag, sometimes not.  I'm guessing that the messages tag needs to be inside of an a4j region, but wasn't able to determine this from the RichFaces documentation.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no needs. Ajax region is a key ajax component. It limits the part of the component tree to be processed on the server side when ajax request comes. Processing means invocation during Decode, Validation and Model Update phase. Most common reasons to use a region are:

- avoiding the aborting of the JSF lifecycle processing during the validation of other form input unnecessary for given ajax request;
- defining the different strategies when events will be delivered (immediate="true/false")
- showing an individual indicator of an ajax status
- increasing the performance of the rendering processing (selfRendered="true/false", renderRegionOnly="true/false")

More about this tag you can read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_region.html).